# How to automatically dispatch read-only transactions to slave

Tags: postgresql, spring-transactions, master-slave

I would like all queries from my Spring-Hibernate application executed in a read-only transaction to be dispatched to a PostgreSQL slave and all read-write transaction queries to a master.

While using annotation driven transactions in Spring,  if the transaction is defined as read-only, the PostreSQL driver allows only select queries to be executed, which is obvious, however there is no mention of how the driver would behave in a master slave configuration. For e.g., the MySQL driver has a replication connection class which automatically dispatches read-only transaction queries to the slave.

One solution would be to use multiple Hibernate session factories and use the one pointing to the slave for selects and the other for updates, but that would be too much manual handling. How should I be designing this?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised by the close and down votes on this. The user could've done some research, but if you're going to closevote/downvote, it's nice to explain why and what they might do to ask a more constructive question.

Comment: User could have done some research, but did not want to do so. We could have provided some explanations, but did not want to. Seems reasonable. But explanation is easy - user should do something before asking, not throw the question for others to solve.

Comment: Apologies for not being within the boundaries of the defined rules.

Comment: I have modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a surprisingly complex question and the answer is not simply easy.  You need to keep in mind that you have to have this dispatched in such a way that the layer which does the dispatching knows whether a transaction is likely to be read-only or not.

The cleanest solution is probably to implement the dispatching in your middleware.  This has the advantage of being a functional dispatch-- we know what we are trying to do so let's dispatch there...  Of course functions can create a bit of a knowledge gap in what is read-only and what writes....

The second option is that one could probably dispatch with something like PGPool or the like.  I would expect you would probably want to avoid server-side prepared queries in these cases because the more knowledge you provide the intermediate layer, the fewer problems you will have.